# Jenkins: How do I lint Jenkins pipelines from the command line?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to be able to perform linting on Jenkins pipelines and it seems that Groovy linting is not enough.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17):

## HTTP without crumb.

If you want to use HTTP and don't want to use CRUMB. just add your username and password using the '-u' parameter. Replace *<username>* and *<password>* with the username and password of your user. Also Check that the url of the jenkins server is correct.

```
 curl --user <username>:<password> -X POST -F "jenkinsfile=<Jenkinsfile" http://localhost:8080/pipeline-model-converter/validate
```

[src](https://books.google.dk/books?id=smhZDwAAQBAJ&pg=SA9-PA119&lpg=SA9-PA119&dq=jenkins+linter+http+username+and+password&source=bl&ots=Q4VVa86gC8&sig=xVLWV2lRmCojihmIpCQK7aAdhFI&hl=da&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGqr-M-N_dAhXSIlAKHZTADGEQ6AEwBHoECC0QAQ#v=onepage&q=jenkins%20linter%20http%20username%20and%20password&f=false)

Answer (score 11):

If for some reason you can't use Jenkins server linter, you can use npm-groovy-lint (works with Declarative or Scripted Jenkinsfile, and also groovy shared libraries)

https://github.com/nvuillam/npm-groovy-lint

```
npm install -g npm-groovy-lint

npm-groovy-lint  // in the root directory of the Jenkinsfile
```

Comment: This is really helpful to me. Generally I just want something to check for dumb mistakes, not that the server supports every feature.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like there are two options for linting pipeline scripts, one via the cli on the leader or an http POST call:

Linting via the CLI with SSH

```
# ssh (Jenkins CLI)
# JENKINS_SSHD_PORT=[sshd port on master]
# JENKINS_HOSTNAME=[Jenkins master hostname]
ssh -p $JENKINS_SSHD_PORT $JENKINS_HOSTNAME declarative-linter < Jenkinsfile
```

Linting via HTTP POST using curl

```
# curl (REST API)
# Assuming "anonymous read access" has been enabled on your Jenkins instance.
# JENKINS_URL=[root URL of Jenkins master]
# JENKINS_CRUMB is needed if your Jenkins master has CRSF protection enabled as it should
JENKINS_CRUMB=`curl "$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)"`
curl -X POST -H $JENKINS_CRUMB -F "jenkinsfile=<Jenkinsfile" $JENKINS_URL/pipeline-model-converter/validate
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter

Comment: Be aware that the pipeline linter only works with declarative pipelines. Scripted pipelines are not supported.

Comment: For SSH based one, you might need to add a public key for Jenkins SSHD: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#ssh

Answer (score 4):

In addition to kongkoro's answer, there is a tool to lint Jenkinsfile.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jflint

```
# install
$ npm install -g jflint

# usage
# JENKINS_URL=[root URL of Jenkins master]
$ jflint -j $JENKINS_URL Jenkinsfile
```

What the jflint does is the same as curl in [the official document](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter), and jflint works only with declarative pipelines too. But it's easier to use.

Comment: Shouldn't that install command be `npm install -g jflint` or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

#### SSH

Methods using [Jenkins SSH interface](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#ssh) to run the linter:

1. Enable SSH service in the [Configure Global Security](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/#ssh-server) page and assign the port (e.g. `2222`).
2. Add your Public SSH Key in your user's profile in Jenkins (`JENKINS_URL/user/USER/configure`).
3. Confirm the SSH access by SSHing to Jenkins and run:

   ```
   ssh -l admin -p 2222 localhost help
   ```
4. Validate your local `Jenkinsfile` using the following command on Jenkins box:

   ```
   ssh -l admin -p 2222 localhost declarative-linter < ./Jenkinsfile
   ```

For further details, read [Pipeline Development Tools](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/).

Furthermore, to simplify, you can add the following section to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host jenkins-cli
  HostName localhost
  User admin
  Port 2222
  ProxyJump jenkins-host.example.com
```

Then run: `ssh jenkins-cli declarative-linter < ./Jenkinsfile`.

You can also consider creating the following shell alias (e.g. to your startup files):

```
alias jenkins-lint="ssh jenkins-cli declarative-linter < ./Jenkinsfile"
```

Then just run: `jenkins-lint`.

#### POST

Validate a `Jenkinsfile` by using the following `curl` command:

> `curl --user username:password -X POST -F "jenkinsfile=<Jenkinsfile" http://jenkins-url:8080/pipeline-model-converter/validate`

For details, please read [How to validate a Jenkinsfile](https://sandrocirulli.net/how-to-validate-a-jenkinsfile/) page.

#### VS Code plugin

Using VS Code IDE editor, you can install [Jenkins Pipeline Linter Connector plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=janjoerke.jenkins-pipeline-linter-connector) and configure accordingly to the instructions, so it can post your `Jenkinsfile` to your Jenkins Server via POST request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lint Jenkins pipelines which can be **scripted** or **declarative**. 
Then the best solution is to lint using the `jenkins-cli.jar`.

I tried whatever I could possibly get my hands at but this really looks like the best and most convenient to use.

*Requirements would be - java*

Download the cli jar

```
$ curl -O https://<jenkins-server>/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

Lint the Jenkins pipeline script - either Scripted or Declarative

```
$ java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s '<jenkins-server-url' -auth <username>:<password> declarative-linter < Jenkinsfile
```

*Its always best to use the jenkins server url where it will be placed as that takes care of checking if the necessary plugins, etc are in place for the pipeline to function correctly.*

[Jenkins-CLI](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/)

Comment: It doesn't actually support scripted piplines